# The Beyond - Why'd they do that?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-beyond

At the end of [The Beyond](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5723416) we find out the aliens were actually benevolent in saving the human race, even though at one part in the movie the army attacks

The one part I don't understand as they are journey toward the void the movie makes you believe the soldier is yanked out of the ship and then either the aliens, or the soldier out of fear, detonates a nuclear bomb in his arm.

So This does not seem consistent with the rest of the plot.  If the aliens did it, why? If the soldier did it out of fear, why did the aliens not reassure him they were not a threat as they did the scientist?